# message:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerdeException Invalid precision or scale for decimal type

Tags: java, oracle, hadoop, apache-kafka

I meet some problem i wanna use kafka connect oracle and hdfs then use hive。
message:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerdeException Invalid precision or scale for decimal type

this is my oracle table

```
CREATE TABLE
    T_JR_CCQK
    (
        CC_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
        CC_USER_FK INTEGER,
        CC_DEPT_FK INTEGER,
        CC_YEAR INTEGER,
        CC_MOUTH INTEGER,
        CC_DAY INTEGER,
        CC_STATES INTEGER,
        CC_ZCD VARCHAR2(80),
        CC_CCD VARCHAR2(80),
        CONSTRAINT P_KEY_JR_CCQK PRIMARY KEY (CC_ID)
    );
```

Comment: Can you provide any additional information? There's really not much anyone can tell you based only on a table definition and an error message.

Comment: i use kafka-connector-jdbc。the topic data like this       {"CC_ID":"\u0001`","CC_USER_FK":{"bytes":"\u001Ed"},"CC_DEPT_FK":{"bytes":"\u0003I"},"CC_YEAR":{"bytes":"\u0007à"},"CC_MOUTH":{"bytes":"\f"},"CC_DAY":{"bytes":"\u0012"},"CC_STATES":{"bytes":"\u0002"},"CC_ZCD":{"string":"泰安市"},"CC_CCD":{"string":"海口市"}}